# Is there any difference between initializing a byte with ASCII and Hex form in Java?

Tags: java, hex, arrays, ascii

I am currently using Java to communicate with device through Serial communication. I have to send packet in byte array. I did the following :

```
    byte[] packet = new byte[3];
    packet[0] = 'C'; //char form
    packet[1] = 'C'; //char form
    packet[2] = '2'; //char form
```

Is there any difference from initialize in this way :

```
    byte[] packet = new byte[3];
    packet[0] = 0x43; //hex form
    packet[1] = 0x43; //hex form
    packet[2] = 0x32; //hex form
```

The value should be the same, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are absolutely the same. Both get converted to an `int` with the same value.